# ¿Se puede utilizar Laravel sin bases de datos?

Tags: php, laravel, base-de-datos, mvc

A lo mejor la pregunta es muy tonta pero soy nuevo en Laravel. Actualmente estoy desarrollando un proyecto similar a un blog y se necesita implementar un usuario que seria el administrador. Entonces como solo necesito 1 usuario no le veo sentido a usar una BD. ¿Existe alguna forma de poner el usuario en el código?

Comment: De que es posible lo es, que eso sea buena idea pues definitivo no

Comment: Si es un blog como planeas administrar las entradas que hagas es decir asociarlas a un usuario si este último no existe en la bd, eso sin contar como sabes qué futuro no requerirás de uno

Comment: podes usar sqlite para persistencia de datos

Comment: @aloMalbarez pero estas deacuerdo que si usa sqlite esta usando una base de datos, mientras que la pregunta del OP es como NO usar una BD

Answer (score 0):

Se puede utilizar laravel sin base de datos y/o con una base de datos no creada mediante *migraciones*, aunque de seguro tu blog necesitará publicaciones, tags, categorías o cosas similares que si requerirán de una base de datos para ser almacenados.
Ahora, si quieres manipular sólo lógica en laravel y tener una base de datos externa igual puedes consumir un servicio web en php y almacenar los datos en otro servidor (Aunque claro, en ese caso seria mejor consumirlo directamente desde el lado del cliente).

Ahora, si sólo quieres crear una cuenta puedes hacerlo en el fichero de **enviroment** o **.env** que se encuentra en la raíz de nuestro proyecto. Para eso, creas una variable que se llame `user=miusuario` y  `password=password`.

Una vez tengas creado tu usuario y contraseña podrás acceder a ellos mediante la función `env("nombre_clave")` por ejemplo `env("user")` para obtener el valor.

La ventaja de dejar el usuario en el fichero **.env** es que luego lo puedes llamar desde cualquier lado y cuando lo quieras modificar quedará en un lugar centralizado y no tendrás que buscar archivo por archivo donde haz dejado el nombre de usuario.

Si quieres seguridad puedes poner directamente un hash en la contraseña y luego validar con las funciones de hash que nos entrega laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Si puedes usar el framework laravel sin una baes de datos. Aunque estarías limitando una de las ventajas mas importantes que tiene relacionada don Eloquent, con su potente motor de base de datos que tiene. Tendras disponible todas las funciones de Rutas, Controladores, Modelos y Vistas con la metodologia MVVC Modelo Vista Vista Controlador entre otras funciones que puedes aprovechar como la inclusión de Bootstrap por mencionar algunoas mas.

Por otro lado los archivos que hagas en tu proyecto de laravel pueden incluir código php puro o tradicional. Tu pregunta menciona que deseas o te encuentras desarrollando un Blog o similar y este tipo de proyectos generalmente son creados con bases de datos como Mysql, Sql Server, Postgre Sql, etc etc para almacenar todos los registros de ese Blog.

Intenta ampliar tu conocimiento de este framework y repositorios de proyectos en este lenguaje php.

Te invito a revisar la documentación oficial de Laravel en 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/